# SQL Server TSQL Stored Procedure / Queries Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, report

I have a SQL Server TSQL question. My stored procedure is running 
very slowly. Any advice on improving these queries with set operations
would be greatly appreciated.

Please keep in mind that I have no control over how the data is stored.

I have two tables in the following format:

1. Person ID, Name, DeletedFlag, SchedTotal, WorkedTotal, DeptNum, DeptName, 
   [and 20 other irrelevent columns for this question] It is a temporary table
   that is pre-filled with the persons selected by the user and who the user
   has access to.
2. Person ID, RecordType, Year, HexMap

For each person, there will be either two or zero records for a particular
year. One record for schedule time and one for worked time. The hexmap
is a string (each two characters representing total scheduled or worked
time). I can be up to 732 characters long (one pair for each day), always
starting on Jan. 1. I wrote a function to split the string, so I'm not 
worried about that.

### Result Wanted

The first table SchedTotal and WorkedTotal fields updated with totals
from the second table based on dates chosen by the user. The date
range be be within a calendar year or cross many calendar years.

I can do it, but I think I'm taking way too many steps. Below is what
I'm currently doing. Suggestions appreciated:

A. TEMP RESULT TABLE 1: For each calendar year that is within the user's 
   chosen range of date (While loop): Insert into a temp table the 
   personid, recordtype, and hexmap for the persons listed the Table 1 above.

```
  WHILE (@YearCount <= @YearEnd)
   ....
  INSERT INTO #Tmp_HexMap (personid, hexMap, recordtype) 
  SELECT T1.personid, H.HexMap, H.recordtype 
  FROM [MyDatabase_' + CONVERT(Varchar(5),@DatabaseNum) + '].[dbo].[hextable] H 
  INNER JOIN #Tmp_Persons T1 ON T1.Personid = H.PersonID 
  WHERE Year = ' + CONVERT(Varchar(5),@YearCount)
```

B. TEMP RESULT TABLE 2: Still in the While loop for each year. I 
   count through the rows one by one (inner While loop) for each person
   and insert into another temporary table the decimal results of my
   hex spliter function -- it returns a table variable with the decimal
   results. I add the personid , scheduled or worked date and scheduled
   and worked times.

```
  WHILE (@PersonID IS NOT NULL)
   ....
  INSERT INTO #Tmp_scheduledtime (personid, scheddate, scheduledworkedtime) 
  SELECT @personid as personid, 
  DATEADD(dd,(Row_Number() OVER(Order by (Select NULL))+(@CurrentStartInt-1)-1),@YearStartDate) AS SchedDate, 
  workedtime FROM Report_Maint.dbo.workedtimesplit(@HexMap,@CurrentStartInt,@WorkedTimeDateINT)
```

C. TEMP RESULT TABLE 3 & 4: Outside of the while loops, I insert the totals into temporary tables:

```
 INSERT INTO #Tmp_Grouped1 (personid, ScheduledTotal, WorkedTotal)
 SELECT personid, ISNULL(SUM(scheduledworkedtime),-1.00) From #Tmp_scheduledtime
 GROUP BY personid
```

D. Finally, I update the original table :

```
    'UPDATE #Tmp_Persons ' +
    'SET HoursSched = ScheduledWorkedTotal ' +
    'From #Tmp_Grouped1 TG ' +
    'WHERE TG.Personid = #Tmp_Persons.Personid ' +
  '  AND #Tmp_persons.PeriodBegin >= ' + '''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(24),@DateBegin,121) + '''' + ' ' +
    'AND #Tmp_persons.PeriodEnd <= ' + '''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(24),@DateEnd,121) + ''''
```

Any idea on making these into one or two queries rather than going through the while loops?
Thanks for any assistance!

Mark

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected results/

Comment: Yes I would need you list all your tables and the used columns with sample data and your desired results to help you.

Comment: Assume for simplicity (and line wrapping) that each
year is only 25 days (hex pairs). The user queries
the start range of Jan. 16, 2013 - Jan 18, 2015.
That means we start counting the 2013 hex pairs on
the 16th day (32nd character) and end for the 2015 hex
pairs on the 18th day (36th character).


Temporary Table 1:

PersonID,Name,DeletedFlag,SchedTotal,WorkedTotal,DeptNum,DeptName
1,Joe,N,-1,-1,Dept1,AcctDept
2,Bill,Y,-1,-1,Dept2,Credit
3,Bob,N,-1,-1,Dept4,HR
4,Jill,N,-1,-1,Dept1,AcctDept
5,Marcy,N,-1,-1,Dept2,Credit

Comment: Part 2 Response: --  Temporary Table 2:
PersonID,RecordType,Year,HexMap
1,0,2013,00006060606060000060606060600000606060606000006060    [672]
1,1,2013,00006F606060600000756060606000006F6060600000666060    [693]
1,0,2014,004A6060006060604A60000060604A60000000606060606000    [1566]
1,1,2014,00575B000049645D5A625C00605A572D5347005F585B7F5E00    [1691]
1,0,2015,60606000006060606060000060606060600000606060606054    [1248]
1,1,2015,00000000005F60606060000060606060000000600060606000    [863]
2,0,2015,70606C73006A79606E000000749578687100006F6B9471676F    [1466]

Comment: 2,1,2015,006D776F717179006F6E006A6C7B006B72696D6971007B7569    [1570]
3,0,2014,00006040005F6060606000006060                          [831]
3,1,2014,0060606400606060606000006060                          [964]
4,0,2014,00000000666031606064006060600060000060606060606300    [1502]
4,1,2014,60600000606060606000006060606060000060606060600000    [1632]
4,0,2015,0080666F6D723800767C717B750072696867346C746B756A63    [1641]
4,1,2015,69656E6363006522000063697E6B416D007067696768000000    [1372]

Comment: Bracketed values to the right of Temporary Table 2 are my calculation
of the decimal values based on the date range chosen.

Result Table
------------
1,Joe,N,3486,3247,Dept1,AcctDept
2,Bill,Y,1466,1570,Dept2,Credit
3,Bob,N,831,964,Dept4,HR
4,Jill,N,3143,3004,Dept1,AcctDept
5,Marcy,N,-1,-1,Dept2,Credit

Thanks again for any help.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I don't have specific enough data from your example, but in general you can do a set based UPDATE with a JOIN to accomplish this sort of behavior with no loops and fast performance. Let me make a simple example to demonstrate.

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(ProductID int
,Name varchar(30)
,Price money)

CREATE TABLE NewPrices
(ProductID int
,Price money)
```

To help visualize it, write a join first between these to see the old and new price side by side:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.Name, p.Price as OriginalPrice, n.Price as NewPrice
FROM Products as p
JOIN NewPrices as n on p.ProductID = n.ProductID
```

OK Simple enough JOIN and you can see the prices side by side. Now just change the SELECT to an UPDATE but keep the FROM and JOIN as follows:

```
UPDATE p
SET Price = n.Price
FROM Products as p
JOIN NewPrices as n on p.ProductID = n.ProductID
```

That will match each record in the tables on ProductID and update the value in then p table which is Products with the values from the matching row in the n table which is NewPrices.

Basically a FROM statement is the same as a FOR statement in C like languages, and a SELECT is like a PRINT statement. So the FROM & JOIN are doing the looping that your WHILE statement is. Instead of doing a SELECT you are updating each row of the JOIN of the two tables.

Once you master that, take a look at the MERGE statement in SQL Server and explore what magic that can do.